# Is there a pandas function to "cross apply" a dataframe with itself using a custom function?

Tags: python, pandas

Given a Pandas DataFrame like this:

```
|------|-------|
|col1  |col2   |
|------|-------|
|a1    |abc    |
|a2    |bcd    |
|a3    |kfs    |
|------|-------|
```

Is there a function to efficiently (the actual DataFrame has > 10.000 rows) create a matrix as follows, with using a custom function to determin the numeric field values?

```
|------|-------|------|-------|
|      |a1     |a2    |a3     |
|------|-------|------|-------|
|a1    |1.000  |0.362 |0.643  |
|a2    |0.362  |1.000 |0.364  |
|a3    |0.643  |0.364 |1.000  |
|------|-------|------|-------|
```

What I did try so far:

- Converting the DataFrame to a list and using a nested list comprehension. That, however, is taking too long performance wise.
- Using sklearn pairwise_distance with my custom function defined as a metric. Same performance issue here.

Ultimately, the following representation will be generated:

```
|------|--------------------------------------|
|a1    |{a1: 1.000}, {a2: 0.362}, {a3: 0.643} |
|a2    |{a1: 0.362}, {a2: 1.000}, {a3: 0.364} |
|a3    |{a1: 0.643}, {a2: 0.364}, {a3: 1.000} |
|------|--------------------------------------|
```

Comment: Try numpy outer ?

Comment: Thank you! But how exactly would I use numpy outer with a custom function? I have seen it used for vector multiplications and for addtitions/ substractions but here we're looking at comparing two strings.

Comment: What's the relationship between the first dataframe (the one with abc, bcd, etc) and the second one (the one with numbers)? Where do the numbers come from?

Comment: The second one should result from "cross applying" (I feel like I'm missing the right term for this) the first data frame with itself. Kind of what you get when doing df.dot(dt.T)

The numbers chosen in the example are arbitrary but would i.r.l. result from a word mover distance using wmd-relax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do that would be to create a cross-product between all the possible values of col1, run the calculation for each pair, and then pivot:

```
# dummy data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "col1": [f"a_{i}" for i in range(5)], 
    "col2": range(5)})

# the following dataframe is produced. We're now looking for a way to 
# run some calculation for each combination of col1 x col1
  col1  col2
0  a_0     0
1  a_1     1
2  a_2     2
3  a_3     3
4  a_4     4

df = pd.merge(df.assign(dummy=1), df.assign(dummy=1), on = "dummy").drop("dummy", axis=1)
df["res"] = df.col2_x * df.col2_y
pd.pivot_table(df, index="col1_x", columns="col1_y", values = "res")
```

The result is:

```
col1_y  a_0  a_1  a_2  a_3  a_4
col1_x                         
a_0       0    0    0    0    0
a_1       0    1    2    3    4
a_2       0    2    4    6    8
a_3       0    3    6    9   12
a_4       0    4    8   12   16
```

Comment: yep, this works thank you! it is still on the slow side - but my guess is that results from wmd-relax being slow